# How to use fold expression to instantiate each type in a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

I am trying to create an "object manager" that will create and store instances of a template class. The class takes one template argument and inherits from a base class to allow instances with different template args to be stored in the same container. The types that will be used as template arguments will be provided by the user in a variadic template function.

Below is a minimal example that illustrates the issue:

```
struct A
{
    int m_a = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct B : public A
{
    int m_b = 1;
    T m_t;
};

template<typename... Types> std::vector<A*> generate_a_vec()
{
    std::vector<A*> a_vec; // <--- Need to initialize with a new B<T> for each T in "Types"
    return a_vec;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> a_vec = generate_a_vec<int, float, bool>();

    for(A* a : a_vec)
    {
       std::cout << a->m_a << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Let's assume every `T` we will use has a default constructor. Is there a way to use a fold expression to create a `B<T>` with `new` for each type in `Types` and add the resulting pointers to the vector in `generate_a_vec()`?

Comment: Do you mean `std::vector<A*> a_vec { new B<Types>{}... }` ? But isn't called "fold expression".

Comment: @max66 I tried your comment and that actually works, thanks! I assumed I would need a fold expression to use std::vector::push_back to add each result to the vector. I will make an edit to clarify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly what do you want, you're looking for

```
std::vector<A*> a_vec { new B<Types>{}... };
```

But this isn't "fold expression"; it's a simple variadic template pack expansion and it's available starting from C++11.

An example of "fold expression" (available from C++17) can be the following

```
std::vector<A*> a_vec;

( a_vec.push_back( new B<Types>{} ), ... );
```

where variadic template pack is folding expanded using the comma operator

Comment: My example was a bit flawed, since your 1st method works for what I need to do. But let's assume I wanted to use your second method, i.e a C++17 fold expression. With MSVC I get "error C3520: 'Types': parameter pack must be expanded in this context"

Comment: @yah_nosh - Maybe your MSVC is too old to support C++17? Or you have to add the option to compile C++17? Anyway, I can say that the `push_back()` version compile with both g++ (8.3.0) and clang++ (7.0.1) (both with `-std=c++17`, obviously)

Comment: My bad, forgot to add the command line argument in Godbolt. Tried it again both there and in Visual Studio, works like a charm! Going to accept, thanks again!